# CSS3 animation bug in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, css-animations

I am trying to build a simple CSS3 animation, a pulsing square inside a bigger square (centered).

It seems to work fine except on IE, at the end of the animation the inner square move to up-left of his parent.

I didn't find a solution, help me please. What am I doing wrong?

```
#foo{   
    position: relative;
    display: table;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50px;
    background: #ccf;
}
#foo::before{   
    content:"";
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    left:   50%;
    top: 50%;
    background: #55a;
    animation: 1s ease-in-out infinite pulse;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0%      {   transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(.2,.2); }
    50%     {   transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(.8,.8); }
    100%    {   transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(.2,.2); }
}
```

Here a [JsFiddle of the code](https://jsfiddle.net/wdL1qenm/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How strange. It looks like IE and Edge are having some issue resetting the transforms on subsequent loops.

Although I couldn't find a direct solution to the browser's rendering problem (likely a bug), your sample looks like a great place to use [the absolute centering trick](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/). By not having the extra translate to center it, it works in IE, and is a bit simpler.

### Working Example ([jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hauL9qqp/)):

```css
#foo{
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  top: 50px;
  background: #ccf;
}
#foo::before{
  content:"";
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
  background: #55a;
  animation: 1s ease-in-out infinite pulse;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0%   {transform: scale(.2,.2); }
    50%  {transform: scale(.8,.8); }
    100% {transform: scale(.2,.2); }
}
```

```html
<i id="foo"/>
```

Comment: Oh! I didn't know that method to center tags and you fully solved my problem, thank you. You just helped me twice in one shot